# Symfony mappig database

Tags: symfony

I have installed Symfony project under MAMP htdocs project folder, which works perfect. I them moved on to create a new Boundle, I created it just fine but I found my self in troubles doctrine.....

I am following this tutorial : [Tutorial Link](http://ziad.eljammal.com/intro-symfony-2-entities-doctrine/)

The part I have stumbled on in this tutorial is:

`app/console doctrine:database:create`

When I run this command in my terminal I get this error:

`Could not create database for connection named`symfony
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Looking at this error it that I have wrong parameters to connect to database so I checked the parameters.yml.dis file and this is what i have in it:

```
`parameters:
    database_driver:   pdo_mysql
    database_host:     127.0.0.1
    database_port:     ~
    database_name:     symfony
    database_user:     root
    database_password: ~

    mailer_transport:  smtp
    mailer_host:       127.0.0.1
    mailer_user:       ~
    mailer_password:   ~

    locale:            en
    secret:            ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt

    debug_toolbar:          true
    debug_redirects:        false
    use_assetic_controller: true`
```

I tried localhost instead 127.0.0.1
I tried MAMP database_port: 8889
I tried MAMP password whihc is: root

but i keep on getting the same error

also not to sure if revelant as my apache and phpmyadmi in on MAMP, but when i run this command in my terminal `mysql -u root -p` this is the terminal response: `-bash: mysql: command not found`

Answer (score 1):

### About the SQL login issue

Check `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` in the privileges panel to see if the user root has a password defined or not and if it is allowed to access mysql via localhost (or other hosts) and if it has permissions to any database.

### About the MAMP issue

Since you do not have mysql installed globally, you don't have access to it from everywhere.

Your mysql is installed locally in your MAMP so you can access it using the /path-to-MAMP/bin/mysql or something similar.

Comment: I though it has someting to with this and I have also tried accessing mysql in my MAMP navigated to MAMP/bin/

Comment: Navigate to MAMP directory and use `find -type f -name mysql` maybe it's not in the bin directory (I haven't used MAMP or Macs in general, i know a bit of Windows WAMP/XAMPP and a lot of LAMP).